# Nancy and SignalR Authentication

Tags: signalr, nancy

I think I am missing something here because this shouldn't be this difficult.

I have a nancy IIS hosted application that uses authentication which works (Sets a cookie _nca).  Then I have a signalR hub that needs to get the username of the logged in person so I can then pull the "Group" that the user belongs to.

I thought I would just grab the username from Context.User.Identity.Name but that is empty and the hub appears to think I am not authorized.  I am guessing that there is something else I need to do to tell signalR how to authenticate.

I thought that maybe setting HttpContext.Current.User would help but that apparently didn't do anything either.

I did this by the following

```
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
        pipelines.AfterRequest.AddItemToStartOfPipeline(SetUpContext);
        //pipelines.AfterRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(SetUpContext);
        CookieBasedSessions.Enable(pipelines);

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    }

    private void SetUpContext(NancyContext ctx)
    {
        if (ctx.CurrentUser == null)
            return;
        string[] Roles = { "Recipient" };

        var userIdent = new UserIdent();
        userIdent.IsAuthenticated = true;
        userIdent.Name = ctx.CurrentUser.UserName;
        GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(userIdent, Roles);
        IPrincipal Identity = (IPrincipal)principal;
        HttpContext.Current.User = Identity;
    }
```

I also tried pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline.  Still not having any luck.

Comment: As SignalR 2.0 is based on OWIN your setup would be greatly simplified if you used OWIN for Nancy as well. You can still  use IIS and it would allow you to do powerful things like share authentication modules.

Comment: Yeah I came to this conclusion and started rewritting my application.  Hopefully copy pasting most of my work will still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/gustavo-armenta/CookieAuthenticationSample) using SignalR 2.0 and Cookie Authentication

Comment: Thanks I will look through this. I actually ended up using code for JabbR to solve this but I believe it does a lot more than what I want.